# Flutter: How possible create fixed datepicker timeline?

Tags: flutter, dart

How possible create fixed datepicker timeline?

[image]

When I scroll my list day should be fixed.

Comment: You can use a stack here. lower layer will contain a green circle and top layer will be a scrollable list. Make the list with and Scroll controller and a fixed extent size.

And add a listener on the list scroller. And add the logic accordingly.